# value++ in for loop itself

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

I have a fairly simple questions about a for loop in javascript. I'm trying to increment the value (`j` in my code) after I've run a method, which declares a callback method and in that function I increment the value. But my code breaks, and I'm not sure if it is valid JavaScript. But everywhere I check this is valid javascript code:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

like that one, Statement 3

Here is my code:

```
for(j=0; j <= 5; )
{

    var keyContent = window.localStorage[window.localStorage.key(j)];
    console.log(keyContent);
    var dataForm = JSON.parse(keyContent);

    uploadDataAndImage(dataForm, function(data) {  
        console.log(data);
        if(data){

            console.log("Data good");
            j++;
        }
        else
        {

            console.log("Data bad");
            break;
        }
    });         
}
```

EDIT: Made it work by doing this:

```
var formDataArray = [];
for(j=0; j <= 5; j++ )
{

    var keyContent = window.localStorage[window.localStorage.key(j)];
    console.log(keyContent);
    var dataForm = JSON.parse(keyContent);
    formDataArray[j] = JSON.parse(keyContent);                      
    uploadDataAndImage(formDataArray[j], function(data) {  
        console.log(data);
        if(data){

            console.log("Data good");

        }
        else
        {

            console.log("Data bad");
            return;
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: Increment j in for loop like (j++)

Comment: `uploadDataAndImage` is asynchronous, isn't it? This won't work with a for-loop at all.

Comment: Yeah its asynchronous. I've made it work by using a workaround, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment within your loop, then what you need is a **while loop**:

```
var j = 0;
while (j <= 5) {
    var keyContent = window.localStorage[window.localStorage.key(j)];
  console.log(keyContent);
  var dataForm = JSON.parse(keyContent);

  uploadDataAndImage(dataForm, function(data) {  
    console.log(data);
    if(data){
        console.log("Data good");
      j++;
    } else {
      console.log("Data bad");
      break;
    }
  });         
}
```

Comment: No. Using a `for` loop is perfectly fine and will work the same way.

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code isn't the loop, but the `break` statement. I suggest you change it by a `return` statement

```
for(j=0; j <= 5; )
{

    var keyContent = window.localStorage[window.localStorage.key(j)];
    console.log(keyContent);
    var dataForm = JSON.parse(keyContent);

    uploadDataAndImage(dataForm, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data){

        console.log("Data good");
        j++;
    }
    else
    {

        console.log("Data bad");
        return;
    }
    });

}
```

Comment: Does not work, the application just freezes and crashes. If I put the j++ into the for loop itself like: for(j=0; j <= 5; j++) it works but things aren't uploaded good because it executes the code before its finished thats why I wanted to increment it after the callback